# How to pass values in the object that is linked to human task in jbpm via webservices?

Tags: jboss, jbpm, kie, kie-workbench

How to pass values in the object that is linked to human task via web-services in JBPM 7.15.0?

Comment: Make use of process variable or global variable.

Comment: @Abhijit I want to pass values in object via web-services.